# How to sort directory by file extension and size in bash

Tags: linux, bash, file, unix, scripting

I'd like to make a script that will print all my documents in a folder and sub folders by their extensions, count of how many of that file type and size.

```
    Example: 
    file type | total count | total size
    pdf 30 4.0k
    txt 90 60.0k
```

something like that. I've been able to figure out how to do this except the size part. Any suggestions?

Comment: You can use `du -b file` or `stat -c %s file` to get the size of a file in bytes, if it helps.

Comment: Thanks I knew that but du -b but I'm having trouble figuring out how to use this with by grouping the file types

Answer (score 2):

```
find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 du -k | grep "\.[a-zA-Z]*$" | rev | sed -e "s/\..*\t/\t/g" | rev | awk '{SUM[$2]=+$1} END{for (x in SUM) print x,SUM[x]}' | sort
```

**Explanation**

```
find . -type f -print0
```

finds all files in subdirectories and print them separated by null character (`somefile.abc`)

```
| xargs -0 du -k
```

for each file it it prints it size in kilobytes (`12<TAB>somefile.abc`)

```
| grep "\.[a-zA-Z0-9]*$"
```

select only files ending with dot and some extension (`12<TAB>somefile.abc`)

```
| rev
```

reverse each line characterwise (`cba.elifemos<TAB>21`)

```
| sed -e "s/\..*\t/\t/g"
```

remove every character between dot and  (`cba<TAB>21`)

```
| rev
```

reverse each line characterwise (`12<TAB>abc`)

```
| awk '{SUM[$2]=+$1} END{for (x in SUM) print x,SUM[x]}'
```

sum lines according to extension

Answer (score 1):

With GNU `find` and GNU `awk`:

```
find . -type f -printf '%s %f\n' | awk '{ size = $1; ext = ""; if(sub(/.*\./, "") != 0) { ext = $0 }; total[ext] += size; ++ctr[ext]  } END { PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@ind_str_asc"; for(ext in total) { print ext " " ctr[ext] " " total[ext] } }'
```

Here

```
find . -type f -printf '%s %f\n'
```

prints the size of each file and its name without the directory part of its path, and the awk code works as follows:

```
{                             # for each line in find's output
  size = $1                   # remember the size
  ext = ""                    # isolate the extension
  if(sub(/.*\./, "") != 0) {  # if the sub returns 0, there was no . in the
    ext = $0                  # file name, so it has no extension
  }
  total[ext] += size          # tally up the size and file counters
  ++ctr[ext]
}
END {                         # in the end: print the tallies.
                              # The PROCINFO bit for sorted output is GNU-
                              # specific. In case that's a worry, print
                              # unsorted and pipe through sort afterwards.
  PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@ind_str_asc"
  for(ext in total) {
    print ext " " ctr[ext] " " total[ext]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Resurrecting this with a simplification to work on systems without 'rev'.

```
find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 du -k | grep "\.[a-zA-Z]*$" | awk -F. '{print $1$(NF)}' | awk '{SUM[$2]=+$1} END{for (x in SUM) print x,SUM[x]}' | sort
```

Use a single:

```
awk -F. '{print $1$(NF)}'
```

instead of:

```
| rev \
| sed -e "s/\..*\t/\t/g" \
| rev \
```

Comment: You could even combine it with the `grep` into a single `awk`: `find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 du -k | awk -F. '/\.[a-zA-Z]*$/{SUM[$NF]=+$1} END{for (x in SUM) print x,SUM[x]}' | sort`